# doing a verify on void method which is in constructor using powerMock

Tags: powermock, powermockito

I need to write a test case for constructor of the following class, where there is a void method I need to mock and verify .How to verify that createToken is get called using powermockito ?

```
public class Mytest{

 private Static string token;

 public Mytest(){
      if (token == null){
        createToken();
      }else
      {
        Log.error("log message");
      }
 }

 private void createToken() {
 // logic to create token
 }
}
```

Test class

```
public class TestMytest{

    //set token to null
     PowerMockito.spy(Mytest.class);
     final String token = null;
     Whitebox.setInternalState(Mytest.class,
            "token", token);

     //supress the  createToken() method        
     MemberModifier.suppress(MemberMatcher.method(
                Mytest.class, "createToken"));  

      new Mytest();

      **//verify(??????????)**              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this verification? What you in fact want to do is to check whether the token has been set? BTW Why is it even static? You want to have each instance of the class the same value of the token?

Either add a getter for the token field or make it package private.

```
public class Mytest{

 final String token;

 public Mytest(){
        createToken();
 }

 private void createToken() {
 // logic to create token
 }
}
```

and you can test it like this (I don't remember if Matchers have this method but you get the idea):

```
assertThat(new Mytest().token, Matchers.notNull())
```